# Compiling gcc-7-20170212 on Windows 7-64 with cygwin, ==> wopen error

Tags: gcc, cygwin, windows-7-x64

I get the following error when compiling gcc on Windows7-64 under cygwin.

```
./../zlib/libz.a(libz_a-gzlib.o):gzlib.c:(.text+0x646): undefined reference to `_wopen'
./../zlib/libz.a(libz_a-gzlib.o):gzlib.c:(.text+0x646): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_wopen'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../.././gcc/fortran/Make-lang.in:97: f951.exe] Error 1
```

What is wopen?

This doesn't happen with gcc-6, or with gcc-5.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a problem with building gcc so much, as with building zlib, of which gcc includes a vendored copy.

You may not need to build the vendored zlib if you have the `zlib-devel` package installed in your Cygwin.  You may also need to tweak some flags to gcc's `./configure` but admittedly I have not taken a close look.

That said, to build zlib on Cygwin the following patches are needed: https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/raw/master/zlib/1.2.11-cygwin-no-widechar.patch
https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/blob/master/zlib/1.2.7-zlib-symbols.patch

(Though the latter doesn't apply cleanly to 1.2.11.)  This is because of an attempt to make `gzopen_w` work on Cygwin that isn't quite correct, since Cygwin doesn't have `_wopen`.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I had the same error (with CYGWIN_NT-10.0 x86_64 and the latest zlib-1.2.11) and the following hack solved the problem:

```
$  cd /tmp/zlib-1.2.11    # i.e., go into main dir
$  sed -i 's/defined(_WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__)/defined(_WIN32)/g' gzguts.h
$  make install     # etc.: no more _wopen(...) error
```

Please don't flame me for lack of explanations or understanding... for myself, I was very happy to find that fix, and I hope it may help out someone else.